# Modular exponentiation with large modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I can calculate module exponentiation of square powers of $7$ modulo $35$ or things alike by hand but for computing modulo exponentiation of square powers of $7$ modulo $1000$, then I need a calculator. For instance

$$
\begin{alignat*}{2}
7^1&\equiv7&&\pmod{1000}\\
7^2&\equiv49&&\pmod{1000}\\
7^4&\equiv(7^2)^2\equiv49^2\equiv401&&\pmod{1000}
\\
7^8&\equiv(7^4)^2\equiv401^2\equiv801&&\pmod{1000}
\\
7^{16}&\equiv(7^8)^2\equiv801^2\equiv601&&\pmod{1000}\\
7^{32}&\equiv(7^{16})^2\equiv601^2\equiv201&&\pmod{1000}\\
7^{64}&\equiv(7^{32})^2\equiv201^2\equiv401&&\pmod{1000}
\end{alignat*}
$$
Is there an easier way without using a calculator?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by hand, if you observe $7$ has order mod. $1000$ a divisor of $\varphi(1000)=80$. Indeed, you can check by hand that
$$7^{10}=7^2\cdot 7^8\equiv 49\cdot 801\equiv 249\mod 10000, \qquad 7^{20}\equiv 7^4\cdot7^{16}\equiv 401\cdot 601\equiv 1\mod 1000.$$
Thus $\;7^{2^n}\equiv7^{2^n\bmod20}$. Then you can use that the powers of $2$ mod .$20$  are cyclic:
$$\begin{array}{r|ccccccc}
n&1&2&3&4&5&6&\dots\\
\hline
2^n\bmod 20&2&\color{red}4&8&16&12&\color{red}4&\dots\end{array}$$